Qt открывает проект с кириллицей со сломанной кодировкой
Создавал проект Qt с кириллицей. После открытия проекта файл открылся со сломанной кодировкой, не смотря на это в самом приложении все отображается корректно.
Было:
ui->label->setText("хай");
После повторного открытия проекта  стало:
ui->label->setText("Р”РѕРїСѓСЃС‚РёРј РїСЂРёРІРµС‚");

Файлы нужно сохранять в кодировке UTF-8

Инструменты->Параметры; Текстовый редактор/Поведение. Выбрать кодировку по умолчанию win1251. Но лучше сразу принять за правило сохранять файлы в UTF8

